# How to make a fixed positioned div until some point?

Tags: css, html, fixed

I have a div with applied property `position: fixed;`. I need to stop this property on some height of screen scroll. Any ideas?
I just need the css code only.

Comment: Can't do it with pure CSS.

Comment: hmmm. Ok any Other way but please take the easiest way as I only studied css

Comment: See my updated answer, you can just add one of the code blocks to the bottom of your page (before `</body>`). Don't forget to wrap them inside `<script></script>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with jQuery pretty easily:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   if ($(window).scrollTop() >= target) {  // change target to number
      $("#el").css('position', 'relative');
   }
});
```

or pure JavaScript:

```
window.onscroll = function(){

   if(window.scrollY >= target) { // change target to number
      document.getElementById('el').style.position = 'relative';
   }

};
```

Comment: But I can't get it, shall I write the number in px ? ie (29px)?

Comment: No, just the number (in your case 29)

Comment: Which code are you using? If you used the first one, make sure to include this code *before* my code: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: It worked like a charm. But I've one more issue, The div need to be `position: absolute;` after the `position: fixed;` is stopped. Once it  stops it jumps back to the original position and I want it to stop at it's place not to jump back.

Comment: Okay, wait a minute :)

Comment: @user3289342 wait, do you mean that when you once scrolled down, the position should be absolute no matter what? And also: is it like this now: when you scroll up after scrolling down, the element gets back to `position:fixed`?

Comment: Could you not just replace `style.position = 'relative';` with `style.position = 'absolute';`?

Comment: Yes I need the position to be absolute at it's current view in the screen, not the original place. Yes that what I needed

Comment: I'm so sorry for being late to answer, But I've already done that.

Comment: Try placing the element inside the div where it should remove `position:fixed`, and then in that div where you put that element, add `position:relative`. If you want to change the position too you can just add: ` document.getElementById('el').style.top = Y; document.getElementById('el').style.left = X;` and replace `X` and `Y` with the values you want.

Comment: No it isn't. , The button is `position:fixed;` when I scroll to footer 
the `position:absolute;` is applied and on doing that the div return back to the original position

Comment: Solved it sir, by creating dual effects in if statement

Comment: <script >window.addEventListener("scroll",function() { 
   if(window.scrollY >= 250) {
   document.getElementById('main_nav').style.position = 'absolute';
   document.getElementById('main_nav').style.top = '82%';
   }
   if(window.scrollY <= 250){
   document.getElementById('main_nav').style.position = 'fixed';
   document.getElementById('main_nav').style.top = '52%';
   }
});</script>